# Segmentation Fault 11 in while loop dependent on std::map.count()

Tags: while-loop, count, c++14, stdmap

Within the definition of a class template method, the following lambda definition has been included:

```
//lambda

auto fnd_nxt_free = [&] () 
{
  while(m_map.count(it->first))
  {
    DBG_PRINT("it->first:" << it->first)
    DBG_PRINT("m_map.count(it->first):" << m_map.count(it->first))
    DBG_PRINT("distance(m_map.begin(), it):" << distance(m_map.begin(),it))

    if(it->first == keyEnd)
    {
      break;
    }

    ++it;
  }
  return it;
};
```

The lambda is used to increment the iterator to the map, for the purpose of assignment.

For consecutive assignments to the map following construction, the intended logic of the code is to increment the iterator to the next free key position within the specified range, before insertion of the specific value.

The different values used in this particular test are (0,1,'A'), which corresponds to construction, (0,2,'B') and (0,3,'C'). Note that the range is implied as [keyBegin, keyEnd).

The segmentation fault is encountered for the third insertion inside the lambda `fnd_nxt_free`. Notice the debug prints highlighted inside the lambda as part of the source code. The corresponding output (for the third insertion) is as shown below:

```
it->first:0
m_map.count(it->first):1
distance(m_map.begin(), it):0

it->first:1
m_map.count(it->first):1
distance(m_map.begin(), it):1

it->first:1
m_map.count(it->first):1
distance(m_map.begin(), it):2
```

The output of `m_map.count(<key>)` is expected to be 0 when the distance of the iterator from `m_map.begin()` is 2, for the insertion (0,3,'C'). As the debug print output shows, the value of key is printed correctly in the first two cases, but does not increment after that, even though the distance of the iterator from `m_map.begin()` is shown to be 2.

In the case of the second insertion (0,2,'B') the same logic in the lambda works as expected, and the `while()` loop exits when the iterator is incremented past the first key position (0), and the only debug print that is output from the lambda is:

```
it->first:0
m_map.count(it->first):1
distance(m_map.begin(), it):0
```

Thus in the second case, the as the iterator moves past the first key position, `mm_count()` returns 0. However, the same logic fails in the case of the second insertion. I can assure that the rest of the processing before the lambda is hit is exactly the same in both the cases.

Can someone point to the flaw?

**MWE**

```
#define DBG_PRINT(...) (cout << __VA_ARGS__<< endl);

template<class K, class V>
class interval_map{

    friend void IntervalMapTest();

    private:

    map<K,V> m_map;

    private:
    bool did_assign;

    public:

    interval_map(V const&);

    public:

    void assign(K const& keyBegin, K const& keyEnd, V const& val);

    public:

    V const& operator [](K const& key) const;

    public:

    struct comp;

    public:
    void display(void);

};


template<class K, class V> struct interval_map<K,V>::comp{

    bool operator()(pair<K const&,V const&> p, V const& v) const{

        return(p.second < v);
    }

    bool operator()(V const& v, pair<K const&, V const&> p) const{

        return(v < p.second);

    }

};


template<class K, class V> interval_map<K,V>::interval_map(V const& val){

    m_map.insert(m_map.begin(), make_pair(numeric_limits<K>::lowest(), val));

}

template<class K, class V> V const& interval_map<K,V>::operator [] (K const& key) const{

    return (--m_map.upper_bound(key))->second;
}


template<class K, class V> void interval_map<K,V>::assign(K const& keyBegin, K const& keyEnd, V const& val){


        auto begin = m_map.find(keyBegin); 

        auto end = m_map.find(keyEnd);

        auto p = equal_range(begin,end,val,comp());

        auto it = p.first;

       //lambda

       auto fnd_nxt_free = [&] (){

           LINE

            while(
                    m_map.count(it->first)
                  ){
                    DBG_PRINT("it->first:" << it->first)
                    DBG_PRINT("m_map.count(it->first):" << m_map.count(it->first))
                    DBG_PRINT("distance(m_map.begin(), it):" << distance(m_map.begin(), it))


                      if(it->first == keyEnd){

                            break;
                        }

                        ++it;
                  }

                   return it;
                };

        if(it == end)
        {

            it = m_map.begin();

            next(it,keyBegin);

            fnd_nxt_free();

           if(it->first < keyEnd){

              m_map.insert(make_pair(it->first,val));
           }
        }
        else{

                if(p.second == end){

                         auto tmpKey = it->first;

                         do
                         {

                           if(fnd_nxt_free()->first < keyEnd)
                           {

                                if( fnd_nxt_free()->first - tmpKey < 2) 
                                {

                                 if(it == end){

                                     break;
                                 }

                                 ++it;

                                 continue;
                             }
                             else
                             {

                                  if(it->first < keyEnd){

                                    m_map.insert(make_pair(it->first, val)); 
                                  }
                            }
                       }

                    }while(it->first < keyEnd);
                }
                else{

                        it = p.second;

                        fnd_nxt_free();

                        if(it->first < keyEnd){

                            m_map.insert(make_pair(it->first,val));
                        }
                }
        }

    }


template<class K, class V> void interval_map<K,V>::display(){

for(auto i : m_map){

    cout << i.first;

    cout << " ";

    cout << i.second;

    cout << endl;

 }

}

void IntervalMapTest(){

  interval_map<unsigned int, char> iMap('A');

  iMap.assign(0,2,'B');

  iMap.assign(0,3,'C');

  iMap.display();

  return;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example.

Comment: @AndreasUnterweger added to the original post

Comment: That code makes little sense. If `it` is a valid iterator into `m_map`, then `m_map.count(it->first)` will always return 1, by definition - you are checking whether an element of the map is present in that same map. If `it` may not be a valid iterator into `m_map`, then `distance(m_map.begin(),it)` exhibits undefined behavior. My guess is, you increment `it` all the way to `m_map.end()`, whereupon it's no longer dereferenceable and `it->first` exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik it is set to point to the beginning of the map at the beginning of the method assign(). I am using m_map.count() to figure out whether the particular key slot is free. The first two key slots are taken before the last case (0,3,'C'). In that case, when distance(m_map.begin(),it) is 2, I would expect m_map.count() to return 0 and the loop should break.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "key slot", and what it means for it to be "free". If `it` is a valid iterator into `m_map` other than `m_map.end()`, then `it->first` is, by definition, some key present in the map - specifically, the key of the key/value pair `it` refers to. Since `it->first` is present in the map, then `m_map.count(it->first)` must needs return 1 - it's defined to return 1 when it's argument is a key present in the map, and 0 otherwise. If, on the other hand, `it` is not a valid iterator or is equal to `m_map.end()`, then `it->first` exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: You call `m_map.count()` passing to it some key taken from that very map. Of course it will always be present. Consider: you have a jar with numbered balls. You pick one ball from the jar, note its number (say, 42), drop the ball back into the jar, and then ask someone: "please check whether ball number 42 is present in the jar". Of course that someone will always find it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik"Returns the number of elements with key that compares equivalent to the specified argument, which is either 1 or 0 since this container does not allow duplicates." Based on the debug print, the logic works for the first case (0,2,'B'), where m_map.count() returns 0 and the loop exits. I have highlighted this in the my original post.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik In that case, I am not sure how the logic works for the case (0,2,'B')? How does the loop exit then, based on the same logic?

Comment: `it` likely becomes an invalid iterator or equal to `m_map.end()` in this case. Whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior, when it attempts to dereference such iterator. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior, "segmentation fault" is another.